# How to take a picture hands free in Android?

Tags: android, camera, automation

I am making an automation program in Android for a robotics team. We need to be able to activate the camera and take a picture, which was no problem, until we realized the way our code was set up (unfortunately in an App Inventor environment, meaning I do not have the src code for that) required the button on the screen to be pressed to take the picture, and we cannot do this in an autonomous phase.

Any way to tell Android to take a picture without pressing that button? I have seen automated apps on the Play Store, but those use voice commands. Any ideas or advice on how to do this? I have some Android experience, but photos are not my forte.

I'd like to paste some code, but I have really no idea of where to even start with this sort of project. I could really use some help.

Comment: Use the camera APIs (`android.hardware.Camera` and/or `android.hardware.camera2.*`), and you can take pictures whenever your heart desires.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use Android Studio, not App Inventor. You'll want to create a `SpeechRecognizer`, then create a `RecognitionListener` and set it with `setRecognitionListener(RecognitionListener listener)`. Then call `startListening(Intent recognizerIntent)`.

Separately, create a callback function: `onResults(Bundle results)` attached to the `RecognitionListener`. If that result hits whatever phrase you decide to set as your "take picture" command, call `takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback)` from the Camera API (follow the instructions in the Camera API instructions from the links below, I recommend using Camera API not Camera2 if you're new to Android development).

These API documentation sites might be helpful to you:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html

If you have further questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpeechRecognizer feature is App Inventor. Yet, before that you have to call "SpeechRecognizer.GetText" function. Then, just add check in "when SpeechRecognizer.AfterGettingText" part.

Next, you also can add check whether the voice is equal to specific text needed to activate the camera. Please make sure the word is in lowercase.

[image]

Comment: Hrundi V.Bakshi, I advise you to visit App Inventor official website. Then, you will understand.

Comment: No, thank you. I prefer real programming. Not toy-development. Even the name is playful. And it reminds me so much of LEGO Mindstorms... I played with those things about 20 years ago.

Comment: Nevermind. People freely to choose in this matter. Yes, it is almost the same as LEGO Mindstorms. ;)

Comment: ... which I don't consider **real** programming. You see, you have to make your fingers dirty, with code. Which is what most of us do, here. I don't think there are many professionals who work with a LEGOish IDE...